# How to run a GO project in eclipse with goclipse installed

Tags: eclipse, go, goclipse

I have installed goclipse in my eclipse and created a new go project.

Now this is what I have:

[image]

And I have hello.go looks like this:

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
     fmt.Println("Hello")
}
```

Then I press run button, or right click the file hello.go, and then run, it gives nothing. Besides, it is also empty in bin folder.

Then I press `run configurations` button, almost empty there with only a project name. it gives:

```
Given Go package not found.
```

This is my Preferences for Go:
[image]

I noticed that both GOROOT and GOPATH are different from those listed in explorer, but once I changed them to C:\Go\src\pkg or C:\Go\src, the Apply and OK button becomes disabled. Besides, I don't have C:\Go\src\pkg folder either.

I can `go install` or `go build` in command line, but I would like to use eclipse for another much larger project. It's windows 7, and the eclipse version is Luna Service Release 1 (4.4.1). Thank you.

EDIT: Now I have the following configurations, and it works fine:
Go is installed at c:\Go
in Preferences: GOROOT:C:\Go, GOPATH: C:\Users\Tiina\go_workspace
The rest in Preferences is filled in automatically.
helloTest project is located at C:\Users\Tiina\go_workspace\src\helloTest
hello.go is located at C:\Users\Tiina\go_workspace\src\helloTest\hello.go
Maybe because I create a project from existing code, and there was something left behind, it automatically adds another GOPATH, in Preferences delete it.

Comment: Is hello.go within on c:\Go\src? Where Go itself is installed?

Comment: @VonC Hi, Go is installed right under C:\ with a path C:\Go, and hello.go is created in the explorer by adding new files, i.e, right click on the project name and then add->file. So now I believe hello.go is in the project root (C:\Users\Tiina\go_workspace\helloTest). I also tried it with hello.go in  c:\Go\src or /helloTest/src

Comment: `GOPATH` should not point to a diretory inside a Go folder.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If `GOROOT` refers to where go is installed (`C:\Go`), then you need to make sure that:

- `GOPATH` differs from `GOROOT` (it is important, because `GOROOT/[src|pkg|bin]` are folders for the Go language itself, not for your own sources)
- `GOPPATH` points to a folder under which all your different Go project will reside (for instance `C:\Users\yourName\Go`: that defines a **[workspace](https://golang.org/doc/code.html#Workspaces)**)
- your eclipse project is created in `GOPATH\src\myproject`

See "[How to Write Go Code](https://golang.org/doc/code.html)" to make sure that your installation and project sources respect the expected organization.

---

The [OP Tiina](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1348691/tiina) reports [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27477855/how-to-run-a-go-project-in-eclipse-with-goclipse-installed/27478923#comment43392452_27478923):

> Now it works, but I noticed two things odd.
>
> - First what I did: I move `helloTest` folder into `C:\Users\Tiina\go_workspace\src`, so now it is at `C:\Users\Tiina\go_workspace\src\helloTest`.
> - Then I create project from existing code. Nothing else changed. Now I have two `GOPATH` in explorer, one is `C:\Users\Tiina\go_workspace\src`, the other one is `C:\Users\Tiina\go_workspace\helloTest\src`.
>     The latter one did no exist at the beginning

I suspect what [goclipse](https://github.com/GoClipse/goclipse) does is define one `GOPATH` per project (or complete the existing `GOPATH`).
If you create or import a project, it will define/complete `GOPATH` in `<that project/src>`
If you hello.go is within that `<that project/src/>` folder, then it should build and work as expected.

The [user guide "project structure" of goclipse](https://github.com/GoClipse/goclipse/blob/54ccc78d67dc6353f6b477fec95be1122e63791b/documentation/UserGuide.md#project-structure) mentions:

> The project location is not part of any `GOPATH` entry.
>   In this case the project location will implicitly be added as an entry to the `GOPATH`, and a Go workspace structure with the `bin`, `pkg`, and `src` directories will be used in the project.
>
> Note that the project's implicit `GOPATH` entry will only apply to the source modules in that project. It will not be visible to other Goclipse projects (unless the entry is explicitly added to the global `GOPATH`).
>
> In the `src` folder you can create Go source files that will be compiled into a library package (and placed into `pkg`), or into an executable (and placed in `bin`)

Comment: Now, in preference, I have GOROOT:C\Go, GOPATH: C:\Users\Tiina\go_workspace, which is also the workspace for eclipse. In helloTest project in explorer, I have GOROOT - C:\Go\src\pkg and GOPATH - C:\Users\Tiina\go_workspace\src. It automatically adds \src\pkg and \src, respectively. In fact, I don't have either of these two folders. When I run it, still "Given Go package not found."

Comment: @Tiina I would really recommend keeping your projects separate from Eclipse workspace. But it should work nonetheless. What the exact full path of your `hello.go` in that new configuration?

Comment: Go itself - c:\Go;  helloTest project: C:\Users\Tiina\go_workspace\helloTest;  hello.go: C:\Users\Tiina\go_workspace\helloTest\hello.go;  GOROOT in explorer: C:\Go\src\pkg; GOPATH in explorer: C:\Users\Tiina\go_workspace\src;  GOROOT in preferences: c:\Go; GOPATH in preferences: C:\Users\cmcc\java_go_workspace;C:\Users\Tiina\go_workspace\helloTest

Comment: @Tiina I can assure you, within a Go workspace (here `GOPATH`), your sources should be in `GOPATH\src`, which means `hello.go` should be in `C:\Users\Tiina\go_workspace\src\helloTest\hello.go`.as described in https://golang.org/doc/code.html. Make sure your eclipse project is created in `GOPATH\src`, and not in the default eclipse workspace (which has nothing to do with a Go workspace described in https://golang.org/doc/code.html).

Comment: Hi, now it works, but I noticed two things odd. First what I did: I move helloTest folder into C:\Users\Tiina\go_workspace\src, so now it is at C:\Users\Tiina\go_workspace\src\helloTest. Then I create project from existing code. Nothing else changed. Now I have two GOPATH in explorer, one is  C:\Users\Tiina\go_workspace\src, the other one is C:\Users\Tiina\go_workspace\helloTest\src. The latter one did no exist at the beginning.

Comment: @Tiina Ok, I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility, as well as a opinion about that working configuration.

Answer (score 1):

Here's what one needs to do. One must always follow GO's convention of the directory structure. In eclipse, once a new project is created just create a "new folder" under the src directory by right clicking on the src folder. And now underneath this folder create a new GO file. I had issues running this on my MAC but by following the above steps was able to resolve.

- Vishal (www.vishalpandya.com)

Answer (score 0):

Please respect the fact, that if you change GOPATH while working in Eclise/GoClipse, you will have to Quit/restart Eclipse in order to Eclipse have the new environment variables to be reread.