# Getting GoClipse to work normally with a normal GO workspace

Tags: linux, eclipse, go, goclipse

I have been trying to use GoClipse (0.8.1v2001409161333 - latest available from the goclipse_feature.feature.group) with Eclipse (4.4.2) on Linux (CentOS6.6) with GO (1.4.2-2.el6) installed via yum from EPEL and have only achieved partial functionality.

Intellisense appears to work fine for the built in packages but GoClipse appears to do something weird with it's directory structure that is different from the normal GO workspace layout.  The existing structure under source control looks like: 
    `$GOPATH/bin/...
    $GOPATH/pkg/...
    $GOPATH/src/externalsite/module/version/*.go
    $GOPATH/src/externalsite/module/version/subdir/*.go
    $GOPATH/src/me/module/*.go
    $GOPATH/src/me/module/feature/*.go`

When I try and use GoClipse it always appears to insist that the *.go files must be a peer of the bin|pkg|src directories.  This means that I either have my *.go files at $GOPATH or tell GoClipse where main.go is ($GOPATH/src/me/module/main.go) and GoClipse creates the bin|pkg|src directories again:
    `$GOPATH/src/me/module/bin/
    $GOPATH/src/me/module/pkg/
    $GOPATH/src/me/module/src/`

My GoClipse configuration has $GOPATH set appropriately (I have tried with $GOROOT undefined or set to the yum install location to no effect) and when creating the Go project from existing code specifying the location as $GOPATH/src/me/module/ (manually expanding $GOPATH)

Some resources that I have located do not appear to offer any advice on getting GoClipse to respect the proper go workspace structure and I am hoping someone can tell me how to do this.
The following resources might be of interest but they do not solve this difficulty:
[How to run a GO project in eclipse with goclipse installed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27477855/how-to-run-a-go-project-in-eclipse-with-goclipse-installed)
https://github.com/GoClipse/goclipse

Comment: I know it's not what you asked but you may want to use another IDE and not GoClipse. try Sublime, IntelliJ, LiteIDE, Atom.

Comment: Yup, I'm going to evaluate IntelliJ and see if I can use an unsanctioned editor (everyone else thinks vi is the way to go and I just don't get on with it).  Thanks for responding

Comment: Latest GoClipse version is 0.10. First try to update to the latest and see what happens.

Comment: Is there a different software site to get this from other than "GoClipse - http://github.com/GoClipse/releases/raw/master/" which lists the version above only?  NB: This is from the eclipse install software window.  Is it necessary to assemble a full eclipse plugin development environment to be able to get anything newer?

Comment: If you already have GoClipse installed, in Eclipse Help -> Check for Updates. It should find that there is a newer version which you can install from the Update window.

Comment: All that happens for me is that after checking some URLs is that a window with "No updates were found" is displayed.  Should I be using a different GoClipse repository URL?  Thanks for taking the time to help me.

Comment: this should be the update site: http://goclipse.github.io/releases/

Comment: Thank you for your help; 10.1 all works using your URL.  Do you want to create an answer so it can be accepted?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Indeed, [goclipse.github.io/releases](http://goclipse.github.io/releases) is the latest update site URL, so you should use the latest version (the URL did change several times since in the span of the previous year). The way Goclipse handles the Go enviroment has changed significantly since 0.8.0, particularly with 0.9.0, which allows creating an Eclipse project on a folder inside a GOPATH 'src' entry. (and other cases are handled better, especially with the builder).

Note: you will need to recreate your Eclipse Go projects after updating (0.10.0 had some internal, non backward-compatible changes).

You might want to consult the changelog for more details: https://github.com/GoClipse/goclipse/releases